# Params for association inside nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, associations, factory-bot, nested-attributes

I have three models. Recipe, Ingredient, Stage.

recipe.rb

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :ingredients, inverse_of: :recipe, dependent: :destroy
has_many :stages, inverse_of: :recipe, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stages
end
```

stage.rb

```
class Stage < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :stages
has_many :ingredients, inverse_of: :stage
end
```

ingredient.rb

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :ingredients
belongs_to :stage, inverse_of: :ingredients
end
```

I'm not sure how strong params should look for recipes_controller. I have something like that at the moment:

```
 def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(ingredients_attributes: [:id, :stage_id] , stages_attributes: [:id])
    end
```

Is it correct? I'm also not sure how rspec test should look for it.

```
 let(:valid_params) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:recipe, :user => user, ingredients_attributes: [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:ingredient, :stage => ???)], stages_attributes: [FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:stage)]) }

it "should create recipe" do
          expect { post :create, :recipe => valid_params}.to change(Recipe, :count).by(1).and change(Ingredient, :count).by(1).and change(Stage, :count).by(1)
        end
```

Comment: Looks good to me. What's your question? Does the test work?

Comment: I'm not sure what should be instead of '???'. How can I link the same stage that is inside of stages_attributes to the ingredient (stage_id).